# UILabel AutoResize cuts off the top part of the text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, uikit, uilabel

I have a UILabel which autoresizes along with its parent view. The label has AdjustsFontSizeToWidth turned on and has a minimum text size of 0 - so basically it tries to fit all the text into whatever size the UILabel is.

The problem I am having is that vertically the text gets cut off. So yes, the label is adjusting its font size to the width of the label but the text is too tall for the label and thus some of the text is getting cut off.

Is there anyway to work around this so that all of the text, the full height and full width are shown?

I attach an image to show what I mean. The red box is the parent view, the purple box is the UILabel.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Text getting cut off]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are adjusting automatically is the Width and not the Height. The Height is something you'll have to adjust manually based on the maximum font size you will use. If the maximum (assigned initial) font size fits in height, so will the smaller one's do, after they are automatically adjusted

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Lefteris is right, that minimum text size focuses on font size for the width of the control. Note, though, if you want it to resize the font to fit, you want a non-zero minFontSize. See [minimizeFontSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/minimumFontSize) notes. Also check out the various [NSString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) that can be used to get the size of the control necessary to fit your text, and programmatically adjust the size (i.e. the frame) your UILabel accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a bogus vertical centering of a view under the labels being clipped and squashed. That somehow took priority over compression resistance priority of 1000 for the labels. No warning on console about conflict though. But the view debugger was of some help.